# Error in codeblocks: free(): invalid pointer

Tags: compiling

So, I just installed Code::Blocks by downloading the source code from the official site, and then run the `./configure` command, `autoreconf -f -i`, `make` and then `make install`.
Everything works just fine until I can't find the program through the menu, and when I type `codeblocks` on terminal it returns:

`*** Error in codeblocks: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fc6af2654d9 ***`.

Did I make a mistake during installation? Or the program didn't installed properly?

Note: I've installed older version of Code::Blocks before, and uninstall it immediately after knowing that there's a new version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks is installed properly, but it isn't working properly. When you run `codeblocks`, that runs the program, and then it crashes before doing anything useful.

Since you didn't do anything special to build and install, the problem is either on your system or in the source code. If you aren't having any other weird crashes, blame the one program that's buggy. (If you are having other weird crashes, run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/).)

Check if there's a newer version available. If there isn't, check if there's a report of a similar bug. If there isn't, report a bug. Be sure to indicate exactly which version of the source code you downloaded, what version of what distribution you're running, on what processor architecture, and what compiler and version you used. In the meantime, install an older, non-buggy version.